# How to get all elements before <p><strong> tag using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to find all elements before first `<p><strong>` encountered and exit the loop once it found.

```
example = """This should be in before section<p>Content before</p><p><strong>First Title</strong></p>Content of first title1<p>Content of first title2</p><p><strong>Second title</strong></p><p>Content of second title</p></strong>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(example, 'html.parser')

for data in soup:
    print(data.previous_sibling)
    print(data.nextSibling.name)
    if nextSibling.name == '<p><strong>':
       print('found and add before content in variable')
```

Output variable should have:

```
This should be in before section<p>Content before</p>
```

**Edit: Tried below code as well**

```
res = []
for sibling in soup.find('p').previous_siblings:
    res.append(sibling.text)
    
res.reverse()
res = ' '.join(res)

print(res)
```

It should check `<p><strong>` not only `<p>` and I am not sure how can I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution maybe other can find useful so posted my answer here:

```
example = """<span>output1</span>This should be in overview section<span>output1</span><p>output 2</p><p><strong>First Title</strong></p>Content of first title1<p>Content of first title2</p><p><strong>Second title</strong></p><p>Content of second title</p></strong>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(example, 'html.parser')

res = []
for sibling in soup.select_one('p:has(strong)').previous_siblings:
    res.append(sibling.text)
    
res.reverse()
res = ' '.join(res)

print(res)
```

Used `p:has(strong)` keywords this I got from @HedgeHog answer thank you for that and I used in my solution.

Comment: May not read your question that carefully, but with slightly differing `example` it makes more sense to me now, *all elements* is not just focusing on *two* as assumed from my side- May use this `example` to improve your question., think this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You could also select the other way around and work with `find_previous`:

```
e = soup.select_one('p:has(strong)')
print(e.find_previous('p').previous, e.find_previous('p'))
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

example = """This should be in before section<p>Content before</p><p><strong>First Title</strong></p>Content of first title1<p>Content of first title2</p><p><strong>Second title</strong></p><p>Content of second title</p></strong>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(example)
    
e = soup.select_one('p:has(strong)')
print(e.find_previous('p').previous, e.find_previous('p'))
```

##### Output

```
This should be in before section <p>Content before</p>
```

Comment: but I am expecting output `This should be in before section Content before` only. Your above code print everything

Comment: Thank you @HedgeHog but it does not solve even I add select. But I have used your keyword `p:has(strong)` and created my solution.